# Google Maps InfoBox or Info Window click eventlistener?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, infowindow, infobox

Is there a way of adding a click eventlistener for an info window or an InfoBox (I'm using that plugin)?

Really the problem I'm having is that the window/box is sometimes getting in the way of a click eventlistener that should be triggered when the user clicks anywhere on the map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the documentation:

http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/docs/examples.html

> Using InfoBox to Create a Map Label
>   This example shows how to use an InfoBox as a map label. One important step is to set the 
>   pane property to "mapPane" so that the InfoBox appears below everything else on the map. 
>   **It's also necessary to set closeBoxURL to "" so that the label will not have a close box,
>   to set disableAutoPane to true so that the map does not pan when the label is added, and to 
>   set enableEventPropagation to true so that events will be passed on to the map for 
>   handling.**

from the example referenced above:

```
    var myOptions = {
             content: boxText
            ,disableAutoPan: false
            ,maxWidth: 0
            ,pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-140, 0)
            ,zIndex: null
            ,boxStyle: { 
              background: "url('tipbox.gif') no-repeat"
              ,opacity: 0.75
              ,width: "280px"
             }
            ,closeBoxMargin: "10px 2px 2px 2px"
            ,closeBoxURL: "http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/close.gif"
            ,infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(1, 1)
            ,isHidden: false
            ,pane: "floatPane"
            ,enableEventPropagation: false
    };

    var ib = new InfoBox(myOptions);
    ib.open(theMap, marker);
```

Comment: Thanks! The code you pasted is incorrect for this problem - 'pane:"floatPane"' needs to be 'pane:"mapPane"', so I initally didn't think your solution was correct. But the text and link you posted was perfect!

Comment: Actually, I should note this has issues as it places the infobox beneath any polyline or markers.

Comment: It doesn't say anything about polylines or markers in your question.

Comment: Nope, I wasn't aware it would be relevant to the solution.

Comment: But I found out that if I add the InfoBox to the 'overlayLayer' pane and set the zIndex high enough it is at least in front of the polyline :)